# Cannot view buttons on LibreOffice

Tags: gnome, libreoffice, 17.10

When I try to open LibreOffice applications on Ubuntu 17.10, all parts work correctly apart from the fact that I can't see any of the buttons.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu 17.10 via an upgrade process?  Did the buttons show correctly earlier?

Comment: Yes, I upgraded from 16.04 -> 16.10 -> 17.04 -> 17.10 and the buttons worked fine even a few days back after I installed 17.10.

Comment: Have there been recent upgrades that you are aware of, and what version of LibreOffice are you running?

Comment: Not aware of any upgrades besides that. Here is the screenshot for version
https://imgur.com/a/PYSyD

Comment: First thing I'd suggest would be to check your user interface settings:  In LibreOffice choose Tools->Options->LibreOffice->View.  Check the User Interface section which deals with icons in the toolbar.  I have 'automatic' for most settings

Comment: Yeah, they are all set to Automatic. https://imgur.com/a/9I3wX

Comment: Ok, the only other suggestion that I would have would be to update to the more recent versions of Libre Office.  I'm using 5.4.3.2 and I've found it to be pretty stable.  I obtain this version from a PPA on Launchpad, and can write instructions about that if you would like.

Comment: Hey, changing it to Tango fixed it. https://imgur.com/a/OrFTK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the icon style within LibreOffice may help with the toolbar display.  To do this, open an instance of LibreOffice and navigate through the menus to 'Tools->Options->LibreOffice->View' - you should see a screen something like what is shown below.

Check the Icon Style, there are several styles to choose from and changing the style may result in an icon set which works with your gnome theme.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton! Sadly, I can't upvote this answer due to low reputation but this worked for me!